# SQL Server query for count sold item in certain dates

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I want to write a query and use a subquery in it, that the result set will be the count of sold item in certain dates.

The table is like this:

```
item_name       sold          date
------------------------------------
A                 20           10.1
B                 10           10.3
A                 10           10.5
C                 20           10.4
A                 30           10.8
```

and the result set will be like this:

```
item_name       sold           date
-------------------------------------
A                 20            10.1
B                 10            10.3
A                 30            10.5
C                 20            10.4
A                 60            10.8
```

Comment: "I wanna write a query" - Please do!

Comment: the date is just a example here i didnt wrote the whole date just the month and day

Comment: So, you want the `sold` column to be the total of all items sold on or before that date, for the same `item_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go with following query

```
select t1.item_name,
      (select sum(sold) from table1 t2 where t2.date <= t1.date 
            and t2.item_name = t1.item_name ) as sold,
       t1.date
from table1 t1
```

isn't it so sipmle ... sql is very simple language ... just you have to think for your problem with calm and cool mind :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.item_name, sum(t1.sold) as sold, t2.date
from myTable t1
    inner join myTable t2 on (t1.item_name = t2.item_name) and (t1.date <= t2.date)
group by t1.item_name, t2.date
```

Comment: thanks a lot that gave me the resultset but i shouldn't use any join clause , i have to use subquery